# Holden Rodeo Headlights Randomly Stop Working and Come Good

Tags: electrical, headlight, lights, holden, rodeo

My 2000 Holden Rodeo has started having issues with its headlights. Randomly the headlight will go out while driving or won't start when I turn them on.

Have tried...

- shaking indicator stalk rapidly between high and low beam
- switching headlights on and off rapidly
- turning engine off and then on again

None of these things fix the issue but randomly the lights will come back on on their own. I have checked all fuses and none of them are blown. Sometimes happens in low beams other times in high beams. My parker lights stay on and my dash lights stay on.

Any tips on where to look to fix it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of cars use relays for the headlights. Being a type of switch they dont just die one day, they become 'intermittent'. Your owners manual or repair manual will show you where its located. They're cheap, try replacing it first.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the grounding wires for the headlamps - usually one for each side.

The connections can be corroded, loose or even the wires broken given the age.
Based on some of the issues you mention then that is a possible cause that I have seen before.